# flutter "Could not find the correct Provider<UserProvider> above this PickupLayout Widget"

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the error "Could not find the correct Provider above this PickupLayout Widget" when I use navigation.push over a showDialog query. Whithout the showDialog popup it works

```
...
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
    child: IconButton(
    icon:Icon(Icons.check),
        nPressed: () {
            query_popup();   // using navigator.push at this position works
           },
          ),
        ),

...

query_popup() {      
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8.0),
            ),
          ),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: 5.0),
              Text("End & save?"),
              Container(height: 20.0),
              InkWell(                        // using navigator.push at this posistion doesn't work
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabbarScreen(SelectedPage: 0)),);
                },
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(width: 10.0, height: 40.0),
                    Text('Yes'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(height: 5.0),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(width: 20.0, height: 40.0),
                    Text('No')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Full error description:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this PickupLayout Widget
This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
  Make sure that PickupLayout is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

Comment: try to wrap your `TabbarScreen` with `Provider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap TabbarScreen with Provider worked, thx @ikerfah